# Configuring a dual monitor with asus hd 5450

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I want to extend my desktop to a second monitor with an `ASUS HD 5450` (dual monitor configuration).

The VGA card has: 1 DVI-D port, 1 HDMI port and a classic VGA port.

I've two old (but functioning) monitor with only VGA port.

I saw online that there are converters `HDMI->VGA` cheaper than `DVI-D->VGA`, my question is:

can I configure the extension of the desktop by connecting a monitor on the VGA port and the other one on the HDMI port (using the HDMI->VGA converter)?

in practice:  can I use the HDMI and VGA ports to configure the dual monitors (extension of the desktop)?
On ASUS site there's nothing that help me.

Comment: The following article explains the different DVI-D connections http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface verify the adapter you are looking at will work before you purchase it.  You should have no problem with the HDMI to VGA cable you are looking at.

Comment: thank you, I had already read on the wiki the DVI specs, but my question relates more to the possibility of the video card to support dual monitor configuration using the VGA port and the HDMI.

Comment: Which I already answered.

Comment: "You should have no problem" is not the answer I'm looking for, but thanks again for your comments

Comment: You asked if using a VGA->HDMI cable with allow you to have a dual monitor setup, my respond was, you should have no problem doing that.  I don't understand how my response wasn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference, any video output can become dual (or more) monitors, for example this is my setup, under linux

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of HDMI2 --auto
xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --rotate left
```

which turns off laptop lcd, makes everything available on two hdmi ports, it wouldn't matter if any or both of them being standard VGA.

by the way, some graphic card have limitations on number of concurrent ports could be activated though i have never seen with with less than two.

hope this helps